# Why is my for loop on JavaScript and DOM manipulation making my website crash?

Tags: javascript, dom

Hi I am a newbie in javascript and DOM manipulation...so I tried doing this to select various buttons and make them give an alert when someone clicks on them.

HTML:

```
<body>

<h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
<div class="set">
<button class="w drum">w</button>
<button class="a drum">a</button>
<button class="s drum">s</button>
<button class="d drum">d</button>
<button class="j drum">j</button>
<button class="k drum">k</button>
<button class="l drum">l</button>
</div>

<script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<footer>
</footer>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
for (var i = 0; i = 6; i++) {
document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
alert("I got clicked!");
});
}
```

When my JavaScript is the following, I am able to click the first button and get the alert, so there is no problem in my link or general format:

```
document.querySelectorAll("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
alert("I got clicked!");
};
```

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i = 6; i++) {` should be `for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {` so you're not assigning any click event handlers

Comment: Take a look at the condition part of the `for` loop, how much sense does it make when assigning 6 to `i`?

Comment: this is infinite loop `for (var i = 0; i = 6; i++) {` change it to `for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using assignment operation inside for loop which is wrong. The right syntax is

```
for(statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
  // code block to be executed
}

Statement 1 is executed (one time) before the execution of the code block.
Statement 2 defines the condition for executing the code block.
Statement 3 is executed (every time) after the code block has been executed.
```

You can replace `i=6` with `i<6` or `i<=6` like so

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
       document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
       alert("I got clicked!");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert("I got clicked!");
  });
}
```

Copy Above code and it will work.
Mistakenly you wrote `var i = 0; i = 6; i++`